# c# button click increase alphabet letter

Tags: c#, increment

I have a button on a c# form that when it is clicked, should change its text value to the next letter in the alphabet sequence.

The default button value is a dash "-" (when the application starts). When the button is clicked, it should change to A, and when it's click again, change to B. At Z, it should reset to A.

I have the following code, however, when the button is pressed, it just returns an open bracket "[".

```
    private void alphaCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = null;
        for (char c2 = 'A'; c2 <= 'Z' + 1; c2++)
        {
            s = c2.ToString();
        }

        alphaCode.Text = s;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a loop in the `alphaCode_Click`, because the cycle happens outside of the "on click" event handler. It's the user who does the looping (by clicking a button); your code performs a single step of that loop.

Therefore, all you need is to pick the letter from the `alphaCode.Text`, add one to it, and set it back into the `alphaCode.Text` field:

```
private void alphaCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = null;
    var current = alphaCode.Text.Length == 1 ? alphaCode.Text[0] : 'A';
    if (current >= 'A' && current <= 'Z') {
        current++;
    } else {
        current = 'A';
    }
    alphaCode.Text = "" + current;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Your suggested code works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A solution that does not depend on the current text value and works for any alphabet:

```
string const Alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int _currentCharacterIndex = -1;

private void alphaCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _currentCharacterIndex = (_currentCharacterIndex +1) % Alphabet.Count;
    alphaCode.Text = Alphabet[_currentCharacterIndex ];
}
```

*(Untested. I don't have access to Visual Studio right now.)*

Answer (score 0):

You are enumerating through *all* the letters as soon as the button is pressed. Basically, you only want to advance your character once per press.

```
private void alphaCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char currentChar = alphaCode.Text[0];

    if(currentChar == '-')
    {
        alphaCode.Text = "A";
    }
    else
    {
        char newChar = currentChar + 1;
        if(newChar > 'Z')
        {
            newChar = 'A';
        }
        alphaCode.Text = newChar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ASCII code of current text as tag for the button. On each click, increase it and change the text. Now, once you have moved through the range (Z that is), reset to a.

Are you dealing with both uppercase and lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

```
      private void alphaCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            char s = Convert.ToChar(alphaCode.Text.Trim());
            if (s == '-' || s == 'Z')
            {
                alphaCode.Text = "A";
            }
            else
            {
                s++;
                alphaCode.Text = s.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the char code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _charCode = 65;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        alphaCode.Text = "-";
    }

    private void alphaCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 90 is 'Z'
        if (_charCode > 90)
            _charCode = 65;

        alphaCode.Text = ((char)_charCode).ToString();
        _charCode++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The char Z is the 90th (dec) in the ASCII table, so when you loop until 90 + 1 = 91, and assign the textBox to it, it shows '[' which is the 91th. For the sake of simplicity, have a `char` created as a field (within the class, not any function or procedure), and everytime the user clicks you just assign the textbox to the current value and then increment it.

```
private void alphaCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     txtAlph.Text = currentChar.ToString();
     currentChar++;
}
```

Then, as a `field`, just use a char to hold the value:

```
char currentChar = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your char as an field. And increase the value of c with every buttonclick. If c = Z then start again on A...

```
char c = 'A'; 
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(c == 'Z'){
        c = 'A';
    }
    label1.Text = c + "";
    c++;
}
```